# Fragment getLayoutInflater() vs. LayoutInflater.from(getContext())

Tags: android, android-databinding, layout-inflater, android-viewbinding

Can anyone explain what's the difference between A and B in the following code snippet?
It's from a `DialogFragment`.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

// A) this works
binding = DialogFragmentPeriodPickerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

// B) this doesn't work: no compiler error, but dialog won't show
binding = DialogFragmentPeriodPickerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

[..] // binding.root is later on passed to setView(binding.root) of MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Fragment `1.2.3`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.3) (or [Fragment `1.3.0-alpha02`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02), which contains the same fix for a `StackoverflowError` when using `layoutInflater` in `onCreateDialog()`), you should always use `layoutInflater`. The fragment's `layoutInflater` is the only one that can correctly inflate `<fragment>` tags or its replacement, `FragmentContainerView` and connect those child fragments to your `DialogFragment` correctly.

However, if you're not using child fragments in your XML, you shouldn't see any difference between the two.

Comment: thanks, I am indeed still on 1.2.2 as the update wasn't shown (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827799/android-studio-not-showing-available-dependency-update) as in the past. Will give it a try and give feedback.

Comment: with 1.2.3 variant B `binding = DialogFragmentPeriodPickerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`  
 works :-)

Answer (score 0):

there is not much difference between layoutInflater and LayoutInflater.from(getContext()) in fact that two are pretty same thing if you look at the source code. problem with your code is that when you call layoutInflater in onCreateDialog its not set yet so our good friend android is trying to set now but it fails. because under the hood it calls onCreateDialog(SavedInstance) yes the function where you mentioned layoutInflater in order to get context from the dialog. so there we have infinite loop which will most likely lead us to crash.

Comment: That's no longer the case per the [Fragment 1.2.3 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.3)