# Android Studio not showing available dependency update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I am on `Android Studio` 3.6.1, in my app `build.gradle` I have e.g.

```
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.2'
```

There is version `1.2.3` [since March 18th](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment), yet no update hint is shown, neither when I hover over the dependency nor in *Module settings* -> *suggestions*.

What could be the reason that the update isn't shown? Can I somehow trigger `Android Studio` manually to search for dependency updates and check when `Android Studio` did so last time?

Comment: The one provided answer is working, that's how I realized there are updates at all. The question is what happened to the old hint? This used to be directly in the editor, not hidden in a menu. Fun fact, if the google ads lib is outdated i get a "warning" inside the editor, but just for this one.

Comment: It was working for me earlier today and it suddenly stopped. I'm wondering if they're enforcing some API request limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manually check for dependency updates by going to:

1. Go to "File"
2. Click "Project Structure"
3. Click "Suggestions" in the left panel

[image: Project Structure]